# break in to vector

Tags: c++, regex

I want to split math expression in to vector so I can apply postfix notation in order to solve the equation. I found this on the Internet but the output is little bit funny. I can't use the `split` method since it removes the delimiter from the result.

```
3+cos(2)+2+1
```

My expected output is:

```
3
+
cos
(
2
)
+
2
+
1
```

but I'm getting something like:

```
3+
cos(
2)
+
2+
1
```

How do I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
vector<string> split(string& stringToSplit)
{
    vector<string> result;
    size_t pos = 0, lastPos = 0;
    while ((pos = stringToSplit.find_first_of("+-*/()", lastPos)) !=         string::npos)
    {
       string value = stringToSplit.substr(lastPos, pos-lastPos+1);    
       result.push_back(value);   
       lastPos = pos+1;
    }
    result.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(lastPos));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string z = "3+cos(2)+2+1";
    vector<string> d = split(z);    
    for(int i=0;i<d.size();i++)
    {
       cout<<d[i]<<endl;
    }    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use iterator and for loop to parse

Comment: please explain further

Comment: Why so many empty lines? This sounds like: "well, I have this homework, but I don't want to waste my time with it - I find something similar on internet, please fix it for me". And I don't see anything about regex here.

Comment: I already search hours but i couldn't get it done that's why i ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string &stringToSplit)
{
    std::vector<string> result;
    size_t pos = 0, lastPos = 0;

    while((pos = stringToSplit.find_first_of("+-*/()", lastPos)) != string::npos)
    {
        string value = stringToSplit.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos);

        if(std::any_of(value.begin(), value.end(), [](char c) { return c != ' '; }))
            result.push_back(value); // or you should trim the whitespaces instead and check whether value is not empty

        result.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(pos, 1));
        lastPos = pos + 1;
    }

    result.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(lastPos)); // the same trimming and check should be performed here
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string z = "3+cos(2)+2+1";
    std::vector<string> d = split(z);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
        std::cout << d[i] << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The code pushes a sequence like `cos` separately to the vector (if it's not only spaces) and then it pushes the delimiter.

Comment: user3635636 - please note that `find_first_of` returns the position of the matched character (like + * / etc). Then, when doing `substr` you had the  range calculation wrong: `pos-lastPos+1` was including the character just found, so the `value` was like `3+` instead of `3`, or `cos(` instead of `cos`. That was core of your problem. Once you fix the calculation like LogicStuff did here, your code would push the "words/numbers" but would stop pushing operators. That's why you then have to push it second time manually and that's why you have to set `lastPos` to something greater than just `pos`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough this is just what i wanted . thank you sir.